# How and from where to download the full DVD of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: server

From where can I download full ISO of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS?

I downloaded an ISO of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server.

This ISO only contains 191 packages.

Thus I need a complete full ISO of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS.

Please suggest me the location and path of the full ISO of Ubuntu Server 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: A complete mirror of the `trusty`, `trsuty-security` and `trusty-updates` for `amd64` takes up ~100 GB. No, you're not going to fit that on a DVD.

Comment: Hello Muru/All

Ok Guide me from where to download the required packages as and when required.

Also from where and how to create the mirror?

Comment: ok so, you want to make a mirror yourself? then you should have asked *that* question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using local packages

What do you mean by full? If it would contain all the available packages, it would not be a DVD. Probably even a BD would be too small. If you need additional packages for offline installation, you can download them with `apt`:

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install package-name
```

Then you can make an image yourself, if you want.

---

#### Creating an Ubuntu mirror

If you want to create an entire mirror, you can use [Rsyncmirror](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Rsyncmirror), it has an extensive guide.

Comment: I m new to UBUNTU.I have worked on other linux flavour like RHEL CENTOS.

So in order to create a kind of yum repository in UBUNTU from where to get the full UBUNTU 14.04.3 LTS ISO.

So that if any person needs any pre-requisite to install a DB on OS person can install the required OS package from that repo

Comment: Added a section about mirroring.

Comment: Can I have the official repository link of UBUNTU 14.04.3 LTS  from where I can download the packages  required??

Comment: Here is a guide: http://www.tecmint.com/setup-local-repositories-in-ubuntu/